# extension to the ball of sphere immersion

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

What are the constraints to extend an immersion of the sphere $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R^3}$ to an immersion of the closed unit ball $B(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Suppose, I get an immersion of $S^2$ into $\mathbb{R^3}$ which is close to $z\mapsto z^3$, where $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is identified with $S^2$. Is it possible that it comes from the restriction to $S^2$ of an immersion from the closed unit ball $B(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: $z \mapsto z^3$ has a branch point and I think that all nearby maps (into $R^3$) do, as well.  So these maps are not immersions.  I couldn't find anything obvious that  addresses your first question.  There are two papers that may be related to what you want: Smale's famous paper "A classification of immersions of the two-sphere" and  Wells' "Cobordism groups of immersions".

Comment: You can approximate $z^3$ with an immersion. I will have a look to your references, thx.

Comment: Just came across this question from 2011; have you ever found an answer?

Comment: As long as the immersion is locally flat (which is also almost certainly required; it is for embeddings) then it should be possible.  This is due to a result by Smale that all locally flat smooth immersions of $\mathbb{S}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ are regular-homotopic.  So they'll all bound.  Sam Nead's comment is correct, btw; that is part of the stable homeomorphism theorem/theory.

Comment: Actually, local flatness isn't always required, but for Smale's result I think it is.